# Adding places to google maps

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a php application that stores Lng-Lat Coordinates to my database.
I would like to show all these places to a google map.

Edit: I have 6000 coordinates, I would like to do this in some way automatically.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map from SQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884035/google-map-from-sql-database)

Answer (score 2):

There are articles for that, which you can find nice and easily on Google

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: Thanks @alex, I have already show that article but it's very old. It's from April 2007

Comment: @paokg4 it says 'Last updated October 17, 2013.' at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

If you have several locations, you can use the following code:

```
var coords = [
    [40.980542, 55.111786],
    [42.329036, 55.222452],
    [44.280249, 54.333]
];

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0][0], coords[0][1]);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "marker : " + (i + 1)
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Check out a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yawrp/) in JSfiddle.

Also, take a look at [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1#adding_a_place).
Its a service that returns information about Places using HTTP requests