# I Can't see my Google Map

Tags: api, maps

Hi Guys :) I have some problem with my Google Maps, well I don't known why I can't see them. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Here is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){    

        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var markersArray = [];
        var infos = [];

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var myOptions = {
              zoom: 9,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        // map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var encodedString;
        var stringArray = [];
        encodedString = document.getElementById("encodedString").value;
        stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

        var x;
        for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
        {
            var addressDetails = [];
            var marker;
            addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");

            var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
            //alert(image + " " + addressDetails[1] );
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                map: map, 
                position: lat,
                content: addressDetails[0]
            });
            markersArray.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
                closeInfos();
                var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});
                info.open(map,this);
                infos[0]=info;
            });
            bounds.extend(lat);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);              

        function closeInfos(){
                    if(infos.length > 0){
                           infos[0].set("marker",null);
                           infos[0].close();
                           infos.length = 0;
                    }
}

    });
```

Here is link to code : https://jsfiddle.net/w1zst7uz/3/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. This line

   ```
   encodedString = document.getElementById("encodedString").value;
   ```

   produces the following error

   > TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

   There is no element with id="encodedString" on your page.
2. Also, center is missing in myOptions. It's a required property (see [Map Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#MapOptions))

   myOptions should look something like this

   ```
   var myOptions = {
       zoom: 9,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}                                
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. But problem is not in TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null, because here I have runing code on my server and the problem is the same,  look : http://imfree.h2g.pl/maps/. 
The funniest think is that here is working map : http://www.macrostash.com/wp-content/plugins/big-ten-demo.php And also I did everything from here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884035/google-map-from-sql-database and nothing. So what is wrong ? :/

Comment: The problem is with myOptions. I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Problem has been solved. The problem was with array rows which generated lat and lng not where they should be, from mySql db,  so I have changed numbers of rows in php part and that's all. If somebody will have the same problem just change rows in php part. Here is working script https://jsfiddle.net/w1zst7uz/4/ and of course link to learn about : http://www.macrostash.com/2011/09/17/demo-use-a-php-mysql-database-to-load-markers-on-a-google-map/. Anatoly You were right - there was NULL :) Thanks for reply and help !